# How to create a date spanning workflow?

Tags: workflow, calendar

I'm having trouble in SharePoint Designer 2010, trying to create weekly emails for all items listed within a weeks time.

So for example I want a weekly email to go out each Monday that will show the listed events for that particular week. These events were created via reoccurring btw.

Was thinking it would be something like a Condition of "If created between Today and (6 days from now?)... but i haven't had any luck getting that span of time.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Update: After working on this a bit further, using the Created By date will not work correctly. As reoccurring Events keep the original created date. I will instead need to use "Start Time" somehow, to make this work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Timer Job instead of a workflow